# Make Typescript enforce all objects have the same structure from two options

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need to make a component of tabs to able show tabs either in icon mode or plain simple text. Instead passing in `variant`, I thought maybe better let the Typescript to check whether one of the icons is having attribute `iconName`, and if so - enforce all the other items to include it as well (by throwing compiler error). If all objects has `iconName`, or all objects don't have it, it's valid.

Here an example and my attempt, to make it clearer:

```
type ObjectWithIcon<T> = T extends { iconName: string } ? T & { iconName: string } : T;

interface MyObject {
  iconName?: string;
  label: string;
}

// This will throw error on second object because of missing iconName
const arrayOfObjects: ObjectWithIcon<MyObject>[] = [
  { iconName: "box", label: "storage" },
  { label: "memory" }, // Error: Property 'iconName' is missing, currently NOT throwing an error
];


// This will not give any error because both has iconName
const arrayOfObjects2: ObjectWithIcon<MyObject>[] = [
  { iconName: "box", label: "storage" },
  { iconName: "circle", label: "memory" },
];

// This will not give any error because no object using iconName
const arrayOfObjects3: ObjectWithIcon<MyObject>[] = [
  { label: "storage" },
  { label: "memory" },
];
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3qg1w) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! This is precisely what I looked for. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how you define `ObjectWithIcon<T>`, you don't want to use the type `ObjectWithIcon<MyObject>[]`, because that's just a single plain array type. Such an array type can't possibly care whether all its elements do or do not have some particular property, the only thing it cares about is whether each element conforms to `ObjectWithIcon<MyObject>`, independently of every other element in the array.

Instead I think you want to use a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of array types, where you say "this is *either* an array of `MyObject`s *with* an `iconName`, *or* an array of `MyObject`'s *without* an `iconName`.

That is, you want a type equivalent to

```
type ObjectsAllWithOrAllWithoutIcon  = {
    iconName: string; // <-- a required property
    label: string;
}[] | {
    iconName?: never; // <-- a prohibited property
    label: string;
}[]
```

TypeScript doesn't really directly encode "without a given property", but you can write "has an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type)", which is pretty close.

---

Anyway, to that end, let's write some utility types to represent "with", "without" and the "either-or" array:

```
type With<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, K>>;
type Without<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Partial<Record<K, never>>;
type ArrayAllWithOrAllWithout<T, K extends keyof T> = 
  With<T, K>[] | Without<T, K>[]
```

The `With<T, K>` type says you've got something which is of type `T`, and also (via [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)), something where the `K` property is required (via [the `Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to grab the part with key `K`, and via [the `Required` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) to say that property is required and not optional).

The `Without<T, K>` type says you've got something which is of type `T`, and also something where the `K` property is optional of type `never` (via [the `Partial` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to say that the property is optional, and via [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) to say that we're talking about something with key `K` and value `never`).
`And finally,`ArrayAllWithOrAllWithout<T, K>`says you've got something which is either an array of`With<T, K>`, or an array of` Without<T, K>`.

---

You can verify that

```
interface MyObject {
  iconName?: string;
  label: string;
}    

type ObjectsAllWithOrAllWithoutIcon = 
  ArrayAllWithOrAllWithout<MyObject, "iconName">;
```

is equivalent to the manually written out `ObjectsAllWithOrAllWithoutIcon` from above.  And that your examples therefore work as intended:

```
const arrayOfObjects: ObjectsAllWithOrAllWithoutIcon = [ // error!
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Property 'iconName' is missing in type '{ label: string; }' 
//  but required in type 'Required<Pick<MyObject, "iconName">>'.
  { iconName: "box", label: "storage" },
  { label: "memory" }, 
];

const arrayOfObjects2: ObjectsAllWithOrAllWithoutIcon = [
  { iconName: "box", label: "storage" },
  { iconName: "circle", label: "memory" },
]; // okay

const arrayOfObjects3: ObjectsAllWithOrAllWithoutIcon = [
  { label: "storage" },
  { label: "memory" },
]; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZZYBAexADk4BbCAfgC5kBnMKUAOYBuClQA2cbBDFde-EMIoBfChTDoADigDqwMAAsAPABUANMgDSyCAA9IIACbdkAawjpaMZMYB8yALzeyABkyABKEACOAK7AUBAOhgAKNC4m5hY+PiLk6lrIuga00WDpltZ2EI7Obh5evgFBoUlwUGDAcGKGEXRQiRbmIBAAbtBZOXkoAIJQUHDoU2JihfqYUIvLevrFpWbltvZOru6e3n6BK2WZANoAusgAPgVbO1c+d6q5mig4+ITcGxWa0BLxKAEk6CBGjM5gslkD1vDQaUML8CGBzAAiGj0JisTHZCgAegAVMhJsg0f8QQZgUiiuDIY1RFQqJdUXh0VicYwWBACXdHsgWayVq8OX8MchsZC8fz3vcKCSiZ8KQBRGwaOCOHrRKDcYCjMToEznIIHKpHWicwgstjmyrVaggGDQSnIe3EZDXKygY51Sm3LgarU6gh6g1Gk2YH23PxKZBcIajKAsrjGHJqb7IABajRD2ocuv1huk0ZtYAB9NWiM2DLAEPohPIpPJ2bzgTIlFZPLlsj4ghyrOQEikMh4A4UOSUgqeXeHvb5nGQ0UcEBgoASQ9Zo+k-fkinIM-uys+kN4yFasMwMCpla4d6rdZrNO2jPojWuyCJROss1oUAAITEr+rIAH4QZBUFQSBVBJFAtBaG06DIAA5IurCodQzjMMA3AGgozptvkqFeru45yIOyBKFhsHINgJTIPEMRxAkREUqhEQsfEiQpAgaQSly0oYfKPioQAdCyXoiVwmLYLQNiYuY5GybwAFwAI-LUaYUkjpIe7SqwzAAegmLacK5C3Jm5AUOeRBXvMN6PgATA+FZPgir47I2UKBNcukydK8mKcp+njpialzJpZlKDp3bSbKfKyQgcQIGI-KhWOslGSZMVxVZ36-rQLjzGe9AXg5WC3u5ADMbmSh5Wx0s+3lMn5ukqdKkUaVpsUdWF2UQMZUCmdpFAFT+yDFfMQA)

Comment: That's a great answer; even though it's a bit hard to grasp the whole concept with the `T` and `K`, it did the job. I'll probably read it a few more times the explanation until it gets through. Thanks so much!